# Determining a relation if reflexive, symmetric, and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I just get stuck in this relation and need to find if this relation is

- Reflexive/ Irreflexive or Neither,
- Symmetric/ Antisymmetric or Neither,
- Transitive or Not.

$$W_1 = \{(a , b)  \in  \mathbb N \times\mathbb N : 2a \geqslant b\}$$

What I have now is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. But I just get confused by the the inequality.

Comment: Do you mean $2a\geq b$?  Does the pair $(a,b)$ mean that $aRb$ is the relation?  I assume that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. That's the notation I am using according to my book.

Comment: Changed it to $2a\geqslant b$.

Comment: @Jose He means to ask if you had a typo, $2a\geq \textbf{a}$ or $2a\geq \textbf{b}$ (emphasis on what it is on the right side of the inequality, another $a$ or a $b$ instead).

Comment: I did emphasize in the right side, and according to the inequality I can have infinite sets, That's why I am confused about evaluating reflexiveness, symmetry and trasitive or not

Comment: @Jose that doesn't answer the question.  In your original edit, you had $2a\geq a$.  That doesn't say anything about $b$ and is a very uninteresting example.  What is more common a question is if it is supposed to be $2a\geq b$.

Comment: Yeah, Let me clarify 2a is greater or equal to b. Sorry about it, I am not used to the math editor (first time posting here)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a\sim b$ when $2a\geq b$ let us first check reflexivity.

> A relation is **reflexive** if $(a,a)\in R$ for every $a$

So, is it true that $2a\geq a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$?

> Is $2a\geq a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$?  Divide both sides by $a$ to see that $2a\geq a$ simplifies to $2\geq 1$, which is always true, so yes, it is reflexive.

As for symmetry:

> A relation is **symmetric** if whenever $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)$ is also in $R$.

If $2a\geq b$, is it automatically true that $2b\geq a$?

> Lets try to find a counterexample:  Simple examples are always helpful.  Consider $(100,1)$.  You have $2\cdot 100 \geq 1$ is true, but $2\cdot 1\geq 100$ is not true, so it is not symmetric.

Antisymmetric?

> A relation is **antisymmetric** if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ and $a\neq b$, then $(b,a)$ is *not* in $R$.

Is it always true that $2a\geq b$ means that $2b<a$?

> Before we tried numbers far apart to find our counterexample.  This time, it looks like numbers close together can cause problems.  So, let us inspect $(3,4)$.  We have $2\cdot 3=6\geq 4$, so $(3,4)\in R$.  How about the reverse, $(4,3)$.  We have $2\cdot 4=8\geq 3$ so $(4,3)$ is also in $R$.  Therefore, it is not antisymmetric.

Finally, transitivity.

> A relation is **transitive** if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, then you necessarily have $(a,c)\in R$.

So, if $2a\geq b$ and $2b\geq c$, is $2a\geq c$?

> Well, $2a\geq b$ means the same as $4a\geq 2b$, and so since $2b\geq c$, we know that $4a\geq 2b\geq c$ and that $4a\geq c$, but it might not necessarily be that $2a\geq c$.  Let us search for a counterexample.  Bad things might happen when the $2a$ is very close in size to $b$, so let us look at pairs of numbers like those.  $(1,2)\in R$ since $2\cdot 1\geq 2$, and $(2,4)\in R$ since $2\cdot 2\geq 4$.  But look at $(1,4)$.  You have $2\cdot 1=2\geq 4$ is not true, so $(1,4)\notin R$ even though both $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ are in $R$.

Comment: What you are explaining in the end implies the relation is not transitive, right? That was great explanation